# Jssor Thumbnail Slider don't go back to 1

Tags: jquery, slider, jssor

I have the Jssor Scrolling-Logo Thumbnail-Slider in my code and i want that the slider don't go back to one, when i switch to the last picture. 
Is there any command that disable this? 
Here the code:

```
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var options = {
            $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
            $AutoPlayInterval: 100,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
            $PauseOnHover: 4,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

            $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
            $SlideEasing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear,          //[Optional] Specifies easing for right to left animation, default value is $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad
            $SlideDuration: 2000,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
            $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
            $SlideWidth: 75,                                   //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
            $SlideHeight: 75,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
            $SlideSpacing: 10,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
            $DisplayPieces: 7,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
            $ParkingPosition: 0,                              //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
            $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
            $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
            $DragOrientation: 1                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
        };
        var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$("slider2_container", options);

        //responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
            if (bodyWidth)
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 980));
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }
        ScaleSlider();

        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        //responsive code end
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set `$Loop` option value to 0.

```
var options = {
   ...,
   $Loop: 0,
   ...
};
```

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html

Comment: That does not working it makes the same as before and i have another problem the width of the slider is to long for my site but the responsive code is in the code.

Comment: Is it possible a picture in the regular slider to center and which command i should use.

Comment: please use `$FillMode` option.

Comment: ok thanks, the problem with the loop when the slide go back are with `$DisplayPieces` when I set it 1 it goes with one pic with more pictures it dont work